# Checkout with new PayPal design

Tags: paypal, checkout

I am using a rather old php script, originally based on the PHP Toolkit for PayPal v0.51 script, for a cart checkout with PayPal.

It uses the variables:

```
url ="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
sock_open ="ssl://www.paypal.com";
pp_hostname ="www.paypal.com";
```

Payment works fine so far, but what do I have to do to lead customers to the new PayPal designed pages for payment?

Thanks
Kashuda

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to force the new PayPal checkout Page.The new design is in the process of being rolled out to the merchants across the globe and would eventually takes time for 100% roll out.

P.S Be informed that the new layout is for Express Checkout workflow.